# How do I ensure javascript is fired after an update Panel has, well, updated?

Tags: c#, javascript, postback

Morning all.

How are we? Excellent I hope.

I have the following little bits of code that I am using to check/uncheck a couple of radio buttons on my page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

function SetOption1RadioButton() {
    document.getElementById('<%=radOption1.ClientID%>').checked = true;
    document.getElementById('<%=radOption2.ClientID%>').checked = false;

</script>
```

I then assign this to a few controls in the code behind and add this to the page load:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            SetJavascriptAttributes();          
        }

public void SetJavascriptAttributes()
        {
                ddl1.Attributes.Add("onFocus", "SetOption1RadioButton()");
                ddl1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "SetOption1RadioButton()");
       }
```

Now this works great on the initial load - lovely stuff. When I click on ddl1, the radio button is set accordingly. However, when the update panel posts back, the javascript no longer works.

I'm thinking this is because the html is sent back and the javascript is no longer there.

How do I go about ensuring that, despite an update panel post back occurring, the javascript stays around a little longer and performs as it should?

Any help or suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using updatepanel's I assume you already have an istance of the `ScriptManager` on your page. I suggest you use the `ScriptManager` to register any client scripts, this will insure they get called on partial postbacks:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript();
ScriptManager.RegisterExpandoAttribute();
```

Comment: Hello dejan - the scriptmanager are placed within a master page - would this make any difference?

Comment: No, it shouldn't make a difference. If you use the static instance of the ScriptManager class it should find the ScriptManager instance on your master page, as long as the Control you put in the 'control' parameter in the above method signure is part of the current Page's control tree (the controls is already added to the page, do not worry about this if you do not add controls dinamycaly to the control tree)

So in short, no.